# Ubuntu 20.04 cannot activate screen sharing

Tags: 20.04, screen, sharing

In Ubuntu 20.04 I cannot activate the screen sharing as you can see below:

[image]

Why the option is grayed? and how can I enable it?

I appreciate your help.