# Ubuntu 20.04 - Cannot use slide to enable screen sharing

Tags: desktop-sharing

In Ubuntu 20.04, I cannot turn on screensharing options. Vino is already the newest version (3.22.0-5ubuntu2.2). I don't have 10 reputation to show images, but I can enable changes to settings (grey slides to purple) but when I try to enable screensharing with the second grey slide, it will not turn purple to be enabled.

I'm not quite sure why I can't slide on the bar for sharing. Any tips? This appears to be a similar issue with others: [Ubuntu 20.04 cannot activate screen sharing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1264025/ubuntu-20-04-cannot-activate-screen-sharing) but I haven't found a solution yet. This is the first time I've used the forum so let me know what I should clarify -- sorry i couldnt add pics. Thank you!!